# Is it possible to get up to 3 decimal places in Float in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I have a table in PostgreSQL, that have a Float column. In my select I use AVG() on that column, so often it gives a number with many decimals. Is there any way to retrict the number of decimals to a maximum of 3, meaning there can be less but not more than 3.

This is the Query:

```
SELECT team, AVG(score) FROM team_score_table GROUP BY team
```

Comment: Do you want to format the result for display or do you want to perform further calculations on the rounded result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a several functions to do that:

```
SELECT round(42.43666, 2) -- 42.44

SELECT trunc(42.43666, 2) -- 42.43
```

or cast:

```
SELECT cast(42.43666 as numeric(20, 2)) -- 42.44
```

according to your example should be:

```
SELECT team, round(AVG(score)::numeric, 2) FROM team_score_table GROUP BY team

SELECT team, trunc(AVG(score)::numeric, 2) FROM team_score_table GROUP BY team

SELECT team, cast(AVG(score) as numeric(20,2)) FROM team_score_table GROUP BY team
```

Comment: I've tried the cast, it returns 20 decimals

Comment: I've been added solution for yours example.

Comment: @Ben: as long as you stick with `float` there is no way to get rid of the decimals. You can only do that with `numeric`. Or format your `float` the way you want when you _display_ the value.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Okay fair enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`round()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html):

```
select round(val::numeric, 3)
```

You can also convert to a numeric, but you need a precision appropriate for your values:

```
select val::numeric(20, 3)
```

I actually prefer the explicit `cast()` because it sets the data type of the column to a `numeric` with an explicit scale -- so downstream apps are aware of the number of decimal places intended in the result.

`round()` returns a `numeric` value but it is a "generic" numeric, with no specified scale and precision.

You can see the difference in [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=619166be579b62ac6c2f911a2f914cab).

Comment: The first suggestion does not work: ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist. I'm not sure you can do that in PostgreSQL.

I don't want to convert the data type, I want it as a float if possible.